# Year fixed effect in time series data

Tags: time-series, fixed-effects-model

I am following one country (USA) over time (2005-2010). In this time series analysis, I want to put a year or a time fixed effect to take into account the variation in the outcome that takes place over time and that is not attributed to my other explanatory variables. However, everytime I run the regression without year fixed effects, everything is good. With year fixed effect (which is just the year going from 2005 to 2010), the entire regression results is basically just the coefficient (no standard errors, t stats, confidence interval, they are all blank). I needed suggestions about how I can add in a time fixed effect, while not messing the results.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "drops out"?  One thing to pay attention to is what observations you assign a year's value to.  If your objective is forecasting, for instance, then it would be invalid to assign an entire year's value to any observation occurring during (or before) that year--it would be tantamount to peeking into the future.  But if you are looking for scientific explanation, are interested in the coefficient, and the year's value is a summary (such as an average) of a regressor, it could make sense to associate that value with *that year's* observations.

Comment: hello @whuber, thanks for your response.

by drop out i mean, the regression results don't have any standard errors/confidence intervals or anything, it's just a bunch of coefficient for the explanatory variables including the year variable
my year variable is all the years from 2005 to 2020, so I gave a i.year in a multiple regression model, with one coefficient of interest and one control. my main objective is to look into the coefficient of interest

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Community, I have fixed the details.

Comment: Do you by any chance have one observation per year?  If so, the year fixed effect would explain 100% of the variability in the observations, so there would be no standard errors etc.

Comment: Yes @jbowman, got this - thanks! Any other way I could incorporate time effects?